# Query builds temporary table with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query:

```
SELECT *, t1.col AS some_col, t5.othercol AS other_col
          FROM t1
          JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.t2_id
          JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id
          JOIN t4 ON t4.id = t1.t4_id
          JOIN t5 ON t5.id = t4.t5_id 
          ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Is slow and CPU intensive. When I EXPLAIN the query, I can see it's building a temporary table and filesort for table 3 (t3). In possible_keys, it says PRIMARY, but it doesn't  use this (key is NULL).

As soon as I make the t3 join a LEFT JOIN, it does use the primary key and is quick again. What could cause this?

Comment: show the schemas and explain(s)

Comment: it is always a good practice to explicitly select the columns instead of `*` when you are selecting from multiple tables.

Comment: Explicitly select the cloumns instead of * as mentioned above. Create a Clustered Index or Non Clustered index on the columns that are used in Joining condition and force the table to use that index. For example 

    USE AdventureWorks 
    GO
    SELECT ContactID
    FROM Person.Contact WITH (INDEX(AK_Contact_rowguid))
    GO

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly select the cloumns instead of * as mentioned above. Create a Clustered Index or Non Clustered index on the columns that are used in Joining condition and force the table to use that index. For example

```
USE AdventureWorks 
GO
SELECT ContactID
FROM Person.Contact WITH (INDEX(AK_Contact_rowguid))
GO
```